# Firebase: How to insert data with a nested structure of child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to ask on how to insert/retrieve data to/from firebase if the database structure is nested as shown in the picture below. Thanks. I'm using java.

Sample database nested structure:

[image]

Comment: Which data/node you want to retrieve?

Comment: from customerID.

Comment: Check my asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebase, you need to:

1. Decide that which node/child you want to fetch
2. Declare a reference to that child
3. Push the data

Simple steps :

Declare and initialize reference

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
           .child("Appointment")
           .child("CustomerID");
```

Define Create and push data:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.setValue(user);
}
```

More details:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#get_a_databasereference
2. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/

Answer (score 0):

have you instance the class ?
did you make the query ?
try this => https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/video-series and get in touch with me after !:))

json is a very good format for structures :)